SQL Alchemy Bulk insertion
Is there a way to bulk insert record into DB with sqlalchemy,
I have a list of tuple and I want to insert them directly into DB with sqlalchemy execute command.
Is there any way to perform the task.
Here is the sample that I want to insert
This is the row_chunk :
[(1001, '1bz', 120), (1002, '7zmk', 150), (1003, '8wqt', 170), (1005, '1qpo', 1100), (1006, '5qop', 4400), (1006, '5qop', 4400), (1007, '22mn', 227), (1008, 'ASDC01', 2000), (1001, None, None), (1010, None, None), (1008, 'ASDC01', 2000), (1002, None, None)]
With this
conn.execute(insert_query, row_chunks)

If you are not using the ORM layer, you can do a bulk insert like this:
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine(...) # Your engine URL here.

# Reflect the table, or get a reference from a model's `__table__` attribute etc.
tbl = sa.Table('name-of-table', sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

# Values should be single dict or a list of dicts.
# Bare tuples were acceptable in versions before 2.0.
values = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, ...]

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(tbl.insert(), values)

Lists of tuples (or a single tuple) were acceptable as values before v2.0.0;
Afterwards values should be single dict or a list of dicts.

Yes , This solution is correct. Works same for  list of tuples.
